# How do I generate a git commit log for the last month, and export it as CSV?

Tags: git, csv, github

Is there a way to generate a git commit log for the last month, and export it as a CSV file? I'm looking for something I can run from the command line, or a 3rd party app. I'd like the following columns: author, date of commit, subject, file edited and hash.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can use the `--since` and `--pretty` option of `git log`, for instance:

```
git log --since="last month" --pretty=format:'%h,%an,%ar,%s' > log.csv
```

Refer to the PRETTY FORMATS section of the [Git log man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) for more options.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you. Is there a way to include (in a separate column) which file was affected/edited?

Comment: This is more tricky, because in general, there is more than one file affected by a commit. Do you want one line by *file* (thus multiple lines for the same commit) or a (semicolon separated?) list of files affected per commit? In any case, this will involve a shell script I guess.

Comment: This is nice. But is there also an option for the last month from the 1th to the last day of it?

Comment: adding quotes would improve the output csv file if the commit messages have commas. "%h","%an","%ar","%s"

Comment: The result for me has the following format: `Commit-ID,User,x hours ago,first line of commit message`

Comment: Edit `~/.gitconfig` to define it as an alias under the [alias] section: `logcsv = log --pretty=format:'%h,%an,%ad,\"%s\"' --date=iso`

Answer (score 44):

This command creates a formatted CSV containing hash,user,date/time,description,files changed,insertions,deletions

```
git log --pretty=format:'"%h","%an","%aD","%s",' --shortstat --no-merges | paste - - - > log.csv
```

Comment: merge commits were messing up the output for me, adding the `--no-merges` parameter helped with that. I also used `%x09` for a tab separator instead of comma for those commit texts containing commas.

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery - Thanks for your comment, `%x09` is really good; I have a repo where commits have both commas and quotes, I thought I was going to have to write a script...

Comment: Creates some annoying vertical spaces for some reason 

Answer (score 10):

To add, if you want to apply date range, add --after or --before in this format "yyyy-mM-d"

```
git log --before="2016-12-1" --pretty=format:'"%h","%an","%ae","%aD","%s",' --shortstat --no-merges | paste - - - > log.csv
```