# Export GIT LOG into an Excel file

Tags: git, logging

I have looked into the forum, but with no luck.

Requirement :

Run GIT LOG (format) command and write the results into an Excel File .

I have seen examples wherein with GIT Log command, data can be written into a CSV, but formatting is double the effort.

Any utility or approach would be helpful.

Thanks 
Milind

Comment: You *could* do something like `git log --oneline | tr "\r" " > ~/gitlog.csv`

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [How do I generate a git commit log for the last month, and export it as CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418056/how-do-i-generate-a-git-commit-log-for-the-last-month-and-export-it-as-csv/10418356).

Comment: This doesn't seem broad or off-topic to me. It is asking how to do something quite specific, and as the top-scored answer shows, it can be done with git-log.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate a git commit log for the last month, and export it as CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418056/how-do-i-generate-a-git-commit-log-for-the-last-month-and-export-it-as-csv)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Git gives your the control on how to format the log output using `pretty` option. Check this out:

```
git log --pretty=format:%h,%an,%ae,%s
```

This prints the log in the format of (hash [abbreviated], author name, author email, subject).

To see the full list of format options:

```
git help log
```

And scroll down until you see the list of format options.

To redirect the output, use `>` redirection operator as follows:

```
git log --pretty=format:%h,%an,%ae,%s > /path/to/file.csv
```

Comment: Great tip, I now use 
`git log --no-merges --since='mm-dd-yyyy' --pretty=format:%h,%an,%ae,%s > c:\dev\history.csv`
weekly

Comment: This answer doesn't escape the output. Here's how you can use a null character `(%x00)` to separate the columns and escape the contents: `git log --format='%h%x00%an%x00%ae%x00%s' | perl -pe 'chomp; $_ = join(",", map { s/"/""/g; "\"$_\"" } split /\0/) . "\n"'`

Comment: You can also use `%ad` combined with `--date=short` to add date column.

Comment: I found I can also quote the values directly in the format - `git log --pretty=format:'"%h","%ad","%an","%s"' --date=iso-strict` - so it's clear when there are commas in the memo

Comment: Excel thinks some of the commit ids are exponential values, and others are regular numbers and removes leading zeroes.

Answer (score 34):

my 2 cents in case anyone is looking:

```
echo "commit id,author,date,comment,changed files,lines added,lines deleted" > res.csv 
git log --since='last year'  --date=local --all --pretty="%x40%h%x2C%an%x2C%ad%x2C%x22%s%x22%x2C" --shortstat | tr "\n" " " | tr "@" "\n" >> res.csv
sed -i 's/ files changed//g' res.csv
sed -i 's/ file changed//g' res.csv
sed -i 's/ insertions(+)//g' res.csv
sed -i 's/ insertion(+)//g' res.csv
sed -i 's/ deletions(-)//g' res.csv
sed -i 's/ deletion(-)//g' res.csv
```

and either save it into `git-logs-into-csv.sh` file or just copy/paste into console.

I think it's relatively self-explaining but just in case:

- `--all` takes logs from all branches
- `--since` limits the number of commits we want to look at
- `--shortstat` - to get some idea what was done in the commit

Comment: As someone fairly obsessed with quantitative data, thanks for this!!! I tried it and this looks cool!

Comment: Thanks, the only downside is the date format, even with --date=short still needs a bit of parsing to be done, but the files/insertions/deletions are worth it

Answer (score 3):

**Simple Solution**

```
git log --pretty=format:%h,%ad,%an,%ae,%s > gitlogs.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers here quite good. I hacked a script based mostly on waht @avs099 proposed, here it is for ease of reference:

```
#!/bin/bash

REPO=$1

DIR=`realpath -L ./$REPO`

echo going to compute stats for $DIR

cd $DIR


git checkout main
git pull
git log --since='last year' --date=short --pretty="%x40%h%x2C%an%x2C%ad%x2C%x22%s%x22%x2C" --shortstat | tr "\n" " " | tr "@" "\n" > res.csv


sed -i 's/ files changed//g' res.csv
sed -i 's/ file changed//g' res.csv
sed -i 's/ insertions(+)//g' res.csv
sed -i 's/ insertion(+)//g' res.csv
sed -i 's/ deletions(-)//g' res.csv
sed -i 's/ deletion(-)//g' res.csv

mv res.csv git-log.csv

awk -i inplace 'BEGINFILE{print "commit,user,date,comment,files changed,insertions,deletions"}{print}' git-log.csv

sed -i '/^$/d' git-log.csv

cd -
```