# Export list of all commit details in VSTS / Azure DevOps into file?

Tags: git, azure-devops, reporting

I want to export a list of all commits in a repository (date-time, author, comment) into a file (of any format: CSV, XML, JSON, XLS etc.) which I will then analyse in a spreadsheet.

I want to compute stats such as:

- number of commits per author per month
- size of each commit (number of lines & files changed, size in kB)
- busiest times of day, busiest days of week, busiest months of year etc.

This is for a high-level management report so non-technical managers can understand the size of effort without blinding them with actual code & architecture details.

There seems to be no obvious way to do this.  I find a few complicated ideas in Git command line documentation but none that yields this info.  Admittedly I am not an expert in Git.

Does anyone know a simple easy way to get high-level per-commit info out of VSTS / Azure DevOps or Git command line?

Intuitively this should be really easy but so far I have to copy/paste each screenful of commits into a spreadsheet and build up the info in steps.  Crazily manual process.  But it's all viewable in the Azure Devops browser interface under Commits so why can't I export it all at once?

Surely I am not the only person on earth who wants to analyse commit activity in this way!  But so far I can find nothing online.

Comment: 'git log' formatted to pseudo-CSV should work. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39269572/717372 with perhaps the '--all' option (git extra could help also to get some statistics : https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/Commands.md)

Comment: Thanks @Philippe - see my answer below

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to @Philippe for guiding to the answer:

- launch MS-DOS command line in the .git subdirectory for the solution
- issue command: `git log --pretty=format:%h,%an,%aD,%s > ./GitLog.csv`
- wait for `GitLog.csv` file to appear and open in spreadsheet program

Format option meanings:

- `%h` = commit hash
- `%an` = Author Name
- `%aD` = commit date
- `%s` = subject (comment of commit)

See here for more: https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats and https://devhints.io/git-log-format

This solution doesn't give number of files or size of each commit, but it's a strong start.

(Philippe if you can move your comment in a proper answer rather, I'll give you the credit for providing the answer)

Comment: this is work good, but in my case which the comments are non-unicode charachters (Perian language), this command results in non-readable charachters for comment. is there any option for **utf-8** encoding output?

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for that same :) Looks that management need similar reports everywhere.

And my solution is more simple i think. After reading AvureDevOps API i realise that we can get all information by simple REST query (it can be executed from a browser as it is GET)

[https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?api-version=5.1&top$=10000](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/git/repositories/%7BrepositoryId%7D/commits?api-version=5.1&top$=10000)

That give all what you need, including number of changes.

Reference to MS Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: The correct format of the top query parameter is '$top', not 'top$'. I can't edit as the edit queue is full. The example URL would then be: https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commits?api-version=5.1&$top=10000