# Azure-DevOps permission to view history without access to code

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to provide a user with permissions to view the history of a project without giving that user access to the code?

Comment: If this could be done from C# using gitsharp or something similar maybe with encrypted credentials, I believe that would be acceptable to everyone here.

Comment: What do you mean by "history of the project"?

Comment: I mean the commit messages normally seen in Repos -> Files -> History

Comment: So, you want a user to be able to audit history of source control while not having access to *modify* source code? Or *view* source code? Also, are you using TFVC or Git?

Comment: Git. Yes, give them the ability to audit history without being able to view any of the source code. It is really the only hurdle moving to Azure Devops.

Comment: Being able to audit history implies access to source code. If you can't see source code, what exactly is being audited? Can you explain more about your scenario?

Comment: For what it's worth, the bottom line answer to your question is "no." If someone can see repo history, they can see source code. I don't think you'll find a Git hosting platform that behaves otherwise.

Comment: I agree fully with @DanielMann, this isn't an Azure DevOps limitation as all git systems work this way. Perhaps you could be more specific as to what requirement you're trying to solve. There may be a better option.

Comment: We are transitioning a set of projects from SVN to Azure DevOps.Currently QA has access to all of the commit logs. They use this extensively during the release process to check against the ticketing system and create release notes. We move fast and sometimes developers commit work that is not ticketed.  We currently have a small tool that uses a built in account with encrypted credentials to read the logs from SVN Server. I believe it uses SVNSharp library to do this. This gives them pretty much everything they need without giving them access to the actual source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as comment mentioned, there is no way to do this in Azure DevOps.

Git uses the parent reference information stored in each commit to manage a full history of your development. Review this commit history could find out when file changes were made and determine differences between versions of your code.

If someone could see repo history, they could also see source code.

As a workaround, you could try to export the history info for commit then give them to the QA user which without access to your code.

- launch MS-DOS command line in the .git subdirectory for the solution
- issue command: `git log --pretty=format:%h,%an,%aD,%s > ./GitLog.csv`
- wait for `GitLog.csv` file to appear and open in spreadsheet program

Format option meanings:

- `%h` = commit hash
- `%an` = Author Name
- `%aD` = commit date
- `%s` = subject (comment of commit)

More details please take a look at this question: [Export list of all commit details in VSTS / Azure DevOps into file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53682298/export-list-of-all-commit-details-in-vsts-azure-devops-into-file)

Comment: This is pretty much where I was headed and will totally meet their needs with only minor changes to workflow.