# Export git log in excel or CSV file saving original comments formatting

Tags: git, csv, logging, escaping

Good morning,
I need to export the git log into a CSV or Excel file, including the comments of the commits.

I found this post that gave me some ideas:
[Export GIT LOG into an Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39253307/export-git-log-into-an-excel-file)

However I have two additional requirement for which I haven't found help so far.

1. I want to preserve the original text format of the comments, including new lines
2. I want to escape the CSV delimiter, in case it is contained in the comments.

Of course, if I can fulfill the point 2), I am open to use any delimiter character.
Could somebody please give an example of git log bash command?

Answer (score 3):

After some test I could find the solution. I have used a git bash script.

```
echo "hash;user;date;comment" > gitlog.csv
git log origin/master --date=local --pretty="%h%x3B%an%x3B%ad%x3BCOMMENTMARK%BCOMMENTMARK" | tr '"' "'" >> gitlog.csv
sed -i 's/COMMENTMARK/\"/g' gitlog.csv
```

One can change "origin/master" in something else if needed.
Explanation:

- I have wrapped each comment in a string marker (COMMENTMARK)
- I have replaced double quotes into single quotes
- I have replaced the comment markers into double quotes

I had to split the escaping of the double quotes in two steps, because the GIT cannot escape characters in comments.

Having wrapped the comments in double quotes allows the presence of new line characters inside the comments.

I hope it can be useful for the community.

---

Edit - I add some clarification details about the purpose of this script. The double quotes around the CSV fields are not only useful to preserve the new line characters inside the comments, but are also necessary in order that the separator characters inside the git comments don't break the CSV file. For example, if the separator is ';', the presence of such character inside the comment would break the CSV. Enclosing the comment in double quotes prevents this. So the only remaining problem would be if the double quote character itself is present within the comment. The proposed solution is to replace the double quotes inside the comment with single quotes.

Note: the CSV would be anyway broken if the git comment contains the temporary tag that is used in the script ("COMMENTMARK"). So the best would be to use a long random string as a temporary tag.

Comment: Here's a variation. I replaced the latter two commands with the following command, to get ISO date format and to use `''` in place of `"` (rather than `'`): `git log origin/master --date=iso-local --pretty="%h%x3B%an%x3B%ad%x3BCOMMENTMARK%BCOMMENTMARK" | sed "s/\"/''/g" | sed 's/COMMENTMARK/\"/g' >> gitlog.csv`